# How can a user login to a workstation if the DC is down?

Tags: domain, local, hashing, workstation

Is it possible to do such thing? 
Because the hash of that users' password is normally stored on the DC..

And if it is, where are the users credentials stored on that workstation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that if your domain admin hasn't disable Cached Login possibility. Again, for full explanation I suggest you to read [another Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994565.aspx).